# Streaming video with videoview

Tags: android, android-videoview

My code below to streaming video:

```
VideoView vv = (VideoView)this.findViewById(R.id.screen_video);
Uri uri = Uri.parse(URL);
vv.setVideoURI(uri);
vv.start();
```

It works.
But if the URL video's format not support by android phone or pad.
It show a dialog, and not show the screen.
But it still streaming with black screen.
I want to get the error message, and access as an exception.
But I don't know how to get it?

Another problem is that the streaming may crash cause by low speed wifi.
How to check it to wait while low speed wifi?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

try this code,it work,

```
public class PlayVideo extends Activity
{


 private String videoPath ="url";

 private static ProgressDialog progressDialog;
 String videourl;  
    VideoView videoView ;


 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
 {

  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.play_video);

   videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);


   progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(PlayVideo.this, "", "Buffering video...", true);
   progressDialog.setCancelable(true);  


      PlayVideo();

 }
 private void PlayVideo()
 {
  try
       {      
              getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
              MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(PlayVideo.this);
              mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);           

               Uri video = Uri.parse(videoPath );             
               videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
               videoView.setVideoURI(video);
               videoView.requestFocus();              
               videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener()
               {

                   public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp)
                   {                  
                       progressDialog.dismiss();     
                       videoView.start();
                   }
               });           


            }
       catch(Exception e)
       {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                System.out.println("Video Play Error :"+e.toString());
                finish();
       }   

 }
}
```

Comment: Right! Another solution is to register the listener `setOnErrorListener`, (on the VideoView object) which allows you to implement the callback `MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener`, that will be invoked when an error occurs during playback or setup.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on which Android Version you are developing your application on. There are certain devices which do not support running .mp4 file. Go through [Android Media support](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html) for more information. Check if you can play any .3gp files or not.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't play the video instantly. Add OnPrepared listener to the video view and start the video playing after it. With MediaPlayer you could keep track of the buffering state and stop the video for a while when its not yet downloaded. Please have a look at [this](http://innovator.samsungmobile.com/cms/cnts/knowledge.detail.view.do?platformId=1&cntsId=9540) guide.

Comment: While I use videoview, it show 03-19 15:02:48.314: V/VideoView(9255): OnBufferingUpdateListener: CurrentBufferPercentage = 100 in the logcat. How can I get the value?

Comment: Thats why I suggested you using MediaPlayer, you can register OnBufferingUpdateListener to it. But I think you can get the same value from video view using videoView.getBufferPercentage()

Answer (score 1):

Try Intent to avoid that error. or put try catch in your block.
VideoView can only Stream 3gp videos but i recommend this code to stream your video

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
setContentView(R.layout.main);
String videourl = "http://something.com/blah.mp4";
Uri uri = Uri.parse(videourl);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "video/mp4");
startActivity(intent);
}
```

Or [Click here to watch Android Video Streaming Tutorial](http://youtu.be/ZKsy81SmPFo).