# Using looper inside AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, looper

I want to display a progress dialog while my video is being loaded and I used `AsyncTask` but got the following error:

```
cant create handler inside thread that has not called looper.prepare
```

then I tried to use looper inside it and still no luck (as it seems `AsyncTask` and Looper are two fundamentally different threading models, which are not compatible)

I have read using `HandlerThread`, but I was not able to find any simple example for it(I usually learn by examples).Please tell me if I need to use `HandlerThread` and if I should, please provide with a sample of using `HandlerThread` like we do in `AsyncTask` for handling a task in background.

That's what I'm doing:
I Just wanted to add that I'm using Vitamio API for playing a flash.

```
class WaitTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog (TvProg.this);
        progressDialog.show();
    }


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Integer... params) {
        videoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(TvProg.this));
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you post some of your code?

Comment: I've now added it to my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried it but I found this example of a progress dialog and a media controller:

[Streaming video with videoview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9765989/streaming-video-with-videoview)

Comment: Thank you, onPrepared method worked fine. I'm still wondering if it can be done by HandlerThread.

Answer (score 1):

create `ProgressDialog` inside `asynctask's` `preexecute()` & `dismiss` that in post execute.

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this..

```
public MyTask(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "", msg, true);

}

/* 
 * @see android.os.AsyncTask#doInBackground(Params[])
 */
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
    //
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(final String result) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();

    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post the full AsynkTask class containing even the header.

Comment: sorry about being unclear, I meant: class WaitTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void> {

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the MediaPlayer only can operate on threads with a Looper. Hence, you should not use an `AsyncTask` for this use case. A `HandlerThread` is much better suited. The progress bar can be controlled by sending messages back to the UI thread before and after you've setup the videoView as shown in some sample code below:

```
mMyBgThread = new HandlerThread("HandlerThread");
mMyBgThread.start();

mBgHandler = new Handler(mMyBgThread.getLooper()) {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        Message uiMsg = mUiHandler.obtainMessage(SHOW_PROGRESS_BAR);
        mUiHandler.sendMessage(uiMsg);

        // Setup videoView          

        uiMsg = mUiHandler.obtainMessage(HIDE_PROGRESS_BAR);
        mUiHandler.sendMessage(uiMsg);
    }
};
```

Now you only have to handle `SHOW_PROGRESS_BAR` and `HIDE_PROGRESS_BAR` on your UI thread.

Comment: Your post seems interesting but I have difficulty making it run(I'm new to Android Development). First, I'm not sure if I should put this code inside onCreate method?! and secondly I don't know where and how to handle SHOW_PROGRESS_BAR and HIDE_PROGRESS_BAR. Could you please post the full solution?